# How to generate integer random numbers that equal to another random number?

Tags: integration, functions, random-variables, generating-functions, simulation

I am running a simulation in Excel, and need to generate a group of integer random numbers summing up to another random integer, how can I possibly do it? For instance I have an integer random number in `A1`, how to have three integer random numbers summing to the value in `A1`? I tried the following: in `A1` I have an random integer

```
round(0,5)
```

In the range `B1:B3` I have

```
randbetween(0,A1)
```

In cell `C1` I put

```
=round(B1/SUM($B$1:$B$3)*$A$1,0)
```

and copied to `C2,C3`. But the problem is occasionally the random numbers will round up to bigger value than `A1`, for instance `A1=3`, when `C1:C3` equal to `0`, `1.5`, `1.5`, they will round up to `0`,`2`,`2` which sum up to `4`. How should I solve it?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What distribution do you want on the triple of numbers adding up to the prescribed value in cell $A1$?

Answer (score 2):

Try these formulas:

\begin{eqnarray*}
B1 &:& \quad\text{=FLOOR(RAND()*(A1+1),1)} \\
C1 &:& \quad\text{=FLOOR(RAND()*(A1+1),1)} \\
D1 &:& \quad\text{=MIN(B1,C1)} \\
E1 &:& \quad\text{=MAX(B1,C1)-D1} \\
F1 &:& \quad\text{=A1-E1-D1} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Columns $D1,E1,F1$ are the three numbers required. $A1,B1$ are two random "dividing lines" between $0$ and $A1$ inclusive. Obviously, you can copy these for as many rows as you want. I've assumed you're interested in integer values only.